# Symfony 2 Project with external data from API

Tags: symfony, sugarcrm

i want to connect a new symfony 2 project with an existing CRM REST API. So i want users to see their CRM data in my project. 
What is the best way to get the data for my entities (Users, Contracts, Tickets etc.) from the external API?

I'm not that familiar with this framework but that are my thoughts:

1. Create entities
2. Create Service for the external API requests to the CRM 
   3.? Connect the entities with the corresponding records in CRM ?
3. Create caching system so that data is only updated every 1 or 2 hours.

Is there a better way and how do i realize point 3. ?

Thanks and best regards

Stefan

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. The easiest one is to not import your data in Symfony, but to get it with Ajax requests from your CRM and add it to your Symfony app. You can use Backbone or ReactJs or AngularJs etc, for that. In this case Symfony will manage everything except the data that is taken from your CRM
2. The other way: create entities for all the data types you will import. Create a service that will manage the data import from CRM. Create a command that will run this service and attach it to a cronjob. In your import service use Guzzle to take the data from your CRM and use JMSSerializerBundle to transform the imported data into entities. You may use this bundle: https://github.com/misd-service-development/guzzle-bundle for this job, it does the integration of Guzzle into Symfony and with the JMSSerializerBundle.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hey, thank you very much for your response. I think I prefer your first suggestion. Can I use the symfony build-in AppCache for cache some requests so that the data is not requested every time the site refreshed? Or is there a better way I have to know for Caching / Sessioning / Saving?

Comment: Great answer, both ways are interesting

Comment: I think it's just a workaround, not solution.

1. First solution seems to be fully frontend-task. But what about caching? Or maybe we already have backend code working with DB source.
2. Existing API may be not importable for some reasons (huge size, speed, reliability).